# How can I use a for loop into function arguments?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, arguments

I'm new at programming in R and I'm trying to create a function that uses a for loop in function arguments. Specifically, I want that the function uses two matrices **(X and Y)** columns as arguments in the **ks.boot** function from **Matching** package, but I'm getting wrong results. Can anybody give an advice about it? Thanks.

```
Ks <- function(X,Y){
X = as.matrix(X)
Y = as.matrix(Y)
require(Matching)
  KS <- list()
N <- ncol(X)
for(i in N){
KS[[i]] = ks.boot(X[,i],Y[,i], alternative = "two.sided")
}}
```

Here is the result I'm getting:

k <- Ks(X,Y)

---

k

---

NULL

Comment: We cannot replicate your error without data. Demonstrate the problem with two small matrices. You really do not need a loop for this as `lapply()` will work nicely: `KS <- lapply(seq_len(N), function(i) ks.boot(X[, i], Y[, i], alternative="two.sided"))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dcarlson for the advice and the solution. The code works perfectly.